# how to safely use JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I get a JSON object, which I then stringify to var embed. The console.log looks like:

```
console.log(send_me_along)

{"provider_url":"https://www.site.com/","description":"Stuff, youâ€™ll need to blah blah","title":"Person detail view & engagement","url":"https://www.site.com/","version":"1.0","provider_name":"site","type":"link"}
```

Then in ajax beforeSend I try to pass this along:

```
settings.data += '&embed_data=' + send_me_along;
```

This is where it breaks. I don't know why. Do you? Something send_me_along breaks and the JSON object never makes it to rails.

```
Started POST "/st" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-12 17:20:25 -0800
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MzDImoksi56IZ1Fa4ldM8jaFyBy61xaWt4bf3z0/3UQ=", "comment"=>{"content"=>"https://www.site.com", "mentions"=>"https://www.site.com"}, "commit"=>"", "embed_data"=>"{\"provider_url\":\"https://www.site.com/\",\"description\":\"Stuff, youâ€™ll need to blah blah.\",\"title\":\"Person detail view ", "engagement\",\"url\":\"https://www.site.com/\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"provider_name\":\"site\",\"type\":\"link\"}"=>nil, "id"=>"ae86c5b7a6"}
```

It appears as if the & in the title is messing up on the post. is there something that needs to be done w jQuery when using settings.data to not allow the stringified data to break everything?

Thanks

Comment: send_me_along is an object, not sure what you want to append to the `settings.data`, did you want a query string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're trying to pass a string of JSON as a url parameter you need to encode it so that special characters that have meaning in a url (like ampersands) will not break things. So something like:

```
settings.data += '&embed_data=' + encodeURIComponent(send_me_along)
```

More info on `encodeURIComponent()` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the data as an object when you call `ajax`?

```
$.ajax(
  //...
  data: {
     stuff: "something"...
  }
);
```

Let jquery deal with the ampersands.

Comment: Good question, I'm using rails UJS, which does all that for me. What I can do is modify the data.settings in the beforeSend callback which is what I'm trying to do... Ideas?

Comment: Should just be able to call `escape` and pass it the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the data.

```
settings.data += '&embed_data=' + encodeURIComponent( send_me_along );
```